# Pyomo error: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, jupyter-notebook, solver, pyomo

I'm a very new Pyomo user. I have been trying to find examples similar to my problem but I couldn't find any that were neither too easy or too difficult. It appears I have a problem initializing a variable but I can't figure out how to fix it. Here's my code:

```
`# Import of the pyomo module
from pyomo.environ import *
 
# Creation of a Concrete Model
model = ConcreteModel()

## Define sets ##
#  Sets

model.I = RangeSet(1, N, doc='Farms')
model.J = RangeSet(1, n_max, doc='Turbines')
model.T = RangeSet(1, T, doc='Time horizon')
model.T_minus_1 = RangeSet(1, T-1, doc='Time horizon up to T-1')
model.R = RangeSet(1, R, doc='Maintenance Crews')

## Define variables ##
#  Variables

model.Xpm_ijt = Var(model.I, model.J, model.T, domain=Binary, doc='Binary variable for shipment decision')
model.Xcm_ijt = Var(model.I, model.J, model.T, domain=Binary, doc='Binary variable for shipment decision')

model.y_rt = Var(model.R, model.T, domain=Binary, doc='Binary variable for shipment decision')
model.z_rit = Var(model.R, model.I, model.T, domain=Binary, doc='Binary variable for shipment decision')
model.f_ijt = Var(model.I, model.J, model.T, domain=Binary, doc='Binary variable for shipment decision')

model.a_ijt = Var(model.I, model.J, model.T,  domain=NonNegativeIntegers, bounds=(0, H*10), doc='Operating time of turbine j at farm i at time t')

#Constraints 
#Constraint 1

def init_a_ijt_rule(model, i, j, t):
    if t == 1 and i == 1:
        if j == 1:
            return 0
        elif j == 2:
            return 0
        elif j == 3:
            return 10
        elif j == 4:
            return 20
        elif j == 5:
            return 23
    elif t == 1 and i == 2:
        if j == 1:
            return 12
        elif j == 2:
            return 20
        elif j == 3:
            return 34
    else:
        return 0

model.constraint_a_ijt = Var(model.I, model.J, model.T, initialize=init_a_ijt_rule, doc='Operating time of turbine j at farm i at time t')

#Constraint 2

def operating_time_rule(model, i, j, t):
    if model.Xpm_ijt[i, j, t].value == 1 or model.Xcm_ijt[i, j, t].value == 1:
        return model.a_ijt[i, j, t+1] == 0
    else:
        return model.a_ijt[i, j, t+1] == model.a_ijt[i, j, t] + 1

model.constraint_operating_time = Constraint(model.I, model.J, model.T_minus_1, rule=operating_time_rule)

#Constraint 3

def PM_rule(model, i, j, t):
    if value(model.a_ijt[i, j, t]) <= (H - h-1) or value(model.a_ijt[i, j, t]) >= H:
        return model.Xpm_ijt[i, j, t] == 0
    else:
        return Constraint.Skip

model.constraint_Xpm = Constraint(model.I, model.J, model.T, rule=PM_rule)`
```

Until the 3rd constraint everything runs fine but I get this error when I run the PM_rule:

`ERROR: evaluating object as numeric value: a_ijt[1,1,1] (object: <class 'pyomo.core.base.var._GeneralVarData'>) No value for uninitialized NumericValue object a_ijt[1,1,1] ERROR: Rule failed when generating expression for Constraint constraint_Xpm with index (1, 1, 1): ValueError: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object a_ijt[1,1,1] ERROR: Constructing component 'constraint_Xpm' from data=None failed: ValueError: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object a_ijt[1,1,1]`

I'm a new Pyomo user, so any help is welcome ! Thank you :)

Comment: You *cannot* write conditional (`if`) statements that depend on the value of a variable.  The variable value is unknown when the math model is constructed.  You will need to reformulate the problem

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things going on here.  The error is coming because in the `PM_rule` function you are calling `value(model.a_ijt[i, j, t])`.  The `value()` function returns the *current value* of the passed variable or expression.  You are getting an error because the variable has not been initialized:

```py
model.a_ijt = Var(
    model.I, model.J, model.T,  domain=NonNegativeIntegers, bounds=(0, H*10),
    doc='Operating time of turbine j at farm i at time t'
)
```

You could provide it an initial value to the variable by passing your `init_a_ijt_rule` to the variable constructor:

```py
model.a_ijt = Var(
    model.I, model.J, model.T,  domain=NonNegativeIntegers, bounds=(0, H*10),
    initialize=init_a_ijt_rule,
    doc='Operating time of turbine j at farm i at time t'
)
```

That said, fair warning: calling `value()` within a constraint rule is almost always *not* what you want to do.  Constraint rules are *not* callback functions: the rule is only called when Pyomo is building the model and not during the solve.  So in this case, the `constraint_Xpm` would only contain (static) constraints based on the initial values of the variables, and those constraints will not change to reflect any updated values that the solver may explore.

Finally, if what you are trying to do is just fix certain variables in your model (i.e., prevent the solver from manipulating them at all), a simpler (and more efficient) approach is to fix the variables with something like `model.Xpm_ijt[1, 4, 1].fix(0)`